# Beckenbach & Bellman $x^2 + y^2 \le 25$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Note: I am going to leave my question as is. But, do look at the answers of dxiv and mathlove below. My question does highlight the limitations of online services like Mathway.

The answer to the exercise is, of course, a circle of less than radius $5$, centered at the origin.

My attempt. $${y}^{2} \le 25 - {x}^{2}$$
$$\sqrt{{y}^{2}} = |y| \le \sqrt{5^2 - {x}^{2}} = \sqrt{(5+x)(5-x)}$$

Concentrating on $|y|$ for $y \ge 0$
$$y \le \sqrt{(5+x)(5-x)} $$

Clearly the radicand $(5+x)(5-x)$ must be $\ge 0$ leading to $$\sqrt{x^2} = |x| \le 25 = 5^2$$ and thus the domain of $x$ is $$-5 \le x \le 5$$

Note that this step makes generous use of set *intersections* and *unions* [Not shown]

The solution now uses the fact that the domain of $x$ in interval notation is $[-5,5]$

In order to find the domain of $y$, it now takes the *intersection* of $2$ sets, ie $y \ge 0$ and the domain of $x$ to finally give the domain of $y$ as $$0 \le y \le 5$$

**This last step, taking the values of 2 domains,  is somewhat of a puzzle.** Clearly it is a legal step, but it is the logic that I want to understand. Is there some rule that makes this step obvious and inevitable?. Clearly it works, but I want more than simply that.

For completeness, we get $$-5 \le x \le 5$$ for $$0 \le y \le 5$$

The solution for $y \le 0$ follows the same steps.

Comment: $-5 \ge x \le 5$ is obviously wrong. Was it a typo?

Comment: Assuming you fixed all typos/errors and got $-5 \le x, y\le 5$ in the end, that would only mean that the locus is inside a square of side $10$. So what exactly are you trying to prove?

Comment: Sorry about the 'typos'.  The part I am struggling with is the interval of $y$. I know it is $\ge 0$, as this is defined as part of the $|y|$. But, how do I show that $y \le 5$ is my question.

Comment: $x^2 \ge 0$ since the square of a real number is never negative, so $y^2 \le x^2 + y^2 \le 25 \iff |y| \le \sqrt{25} = 5$.

Comment: @dxiv  I used Mathway to really dive into this problem, as this is the way I started solving it. Your answer is elegant, but the 'ponderous' answer does expose one to an aspect of set theory - albeit the most basic ones. I would like to really understand both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to find the domain of $y$, it now takes the *intersection* of $2$ sets, ie $y \ge 0$ and the domain of $x$ to finally give the domain of $y$ as $0 \le y \le 5$

If you are saying that the $\color{red}5$ in $0\le y\le\color{red}5$ comes from the $\color{blue}5$ in $-5\le x\le \color{blue}5$, then that is not correct.

The $\color{red}5$ in $0\le y\le\color{red}5$ **does not** come from the $\color{blue}5$ in $-5\le x\le \color{blue}5$.

To understand that, I think considering another example should be helpful.

Let us consider $2x^2+y^2\le 4$.

We have $y^2\le 4-2x^2$. In order for such a real number $y$ to exist, it is necessary and sufficient that $4-2x^2\ge 0$, i.e.
$$-\sqrt 2\le x \le \color{red}{\sqrt 2}$$

If $y\ge 0$, then using $x^2\ge 0$, we have
$$y=\sqrt{y^2}\le \sqrt{2x^2+y^2}\le \sqrt 4=\color{blue}2$$
as dxiv did.

So, $0\le y\le \color{blue}2$.

You can see that $\color{red}{\sqrt 2}$ is not equal to $\color{blue}2$.

Comment: I know you are not supposed to thank -- but thanks for taking the time to answer. So, thanks for pointing out what was clearly wrong. The answer was machine generated and I suspect the algorithm could simply not handle that, and in fact at some point simply said there was no answer.  Could you clarify one step please. ...…$\sqrt{2{x}^{2} + {y}^{2} } \le \sqrt{4}$… I really want to see how you go from the first expression to $\sqrt{4}$, so I can accept this answer.

Comment: @user1115542 : You are welcome. Sure. Let me explain the step. In the first place, we are now considering the example $2x^2+y^2\le 4$. Therefore, we can say that $\sqrt{2x^2+y^2}\le\sqrt 4$. This is because if $X,Y$ are non-negative numbers such that $X\le Y$, we can say that $\sqrt X\le \sqrt Y$. I hope this answers your question in comment.

Comment: Hanging my head in shame!!!  I get it.  And of course, the example you gave is for $y \ge 0$. The same logic would apply when examining $y^2$ for $y \le 0$. I am going to mark you answer as accepted.